# Should I initialize a null state variable in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am still a bit new to React, and I find it awesome, but one thing is currently on my mind and I would like to know what to think of it.

For instance, I am making a checkout component, where i have a reduction coupon field.

I pass the current price of my event to the coupon so that it can calculate the new:

```
{this.state.showCouponField ? (
  <CouponForm
    validateCoupon={(coupon) => this.setState({ coupon: coupon })}
    initialValue={this.state.coupon ? this.state.coupon.token : ''}
    initialPrice={this.state.event.final_price}
    setReducedPrice={(reducedPrice) => this.setState({ reducedPrice })}
  />
) : null}
```

and then display:

```
<p className="lead">
  Total :
  <span className="pull-right">
    {this.state.reducedPrice ? (
      <span>
        <s>
          {isFree ? 'Gratuit' : `${event.real_final_price * this.state.participants} €`}
        </s>
        &nbsp;
        {this.state.reducedPrice === 0 ? 'Gratuit' : `${this.state.reducedPrice / 100 * this.state.participants} €`}
      </span>
    ) : (
      <span>
        {isFree ? 'Gratuit' : `${event.real_final_price * this.state.participants} €`}
      </span>
    )}
  </span>
</p>
```

But for instance, the variable `reducedPrice` is null until someone uses a coupon.

The question is : is it a good practice to set the `reducedPrice` the initial state

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    event: null,
    creditCards: [],
    selectedCardId: null,
    addCreditCard: false,
    participants: 1,
    coupon: null,
    total: 0,
    error: null,
    loading: false,
    bookingId: null,
    user: null,
    showCardOptions: false,
    showModal: false,
    modalUrl: null,
  };

  this.updatePaymentMeans = this.updatePaymentMeans.bind(this);
}
```

All these null variables seem useless to me as they are empty by default et they are not needed - or I have yet to see a bug - to be initialized because the state is an object so it can be created on the fly.

I know I will forget some of these, so I wonder if I would simply not set them so that it would clearly break if I miss one.

Open question :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having them as `null` or `undefined` will lead you to the same results / bugs, since you will rarely use triple-equal to compare its existence.

```
selectedCreditCardId ? something : else
```

But then again, the same thing happens with `true` / `false`, contrary to other types (strings, numbers, ...), you rarely use the triple-equal either.

So it's exactly the same to: `this.state = { isTall: false }`, than not having it at all

`isTall ? yes : no`

will still give you the same results. *(this example is to provide you better context to the links I'll show you later)*

IMO, since that is an opinionated question
Having them defined at the top, contrary to having them spread over the render method, will give a quick overview on what's in the state and what your next state will be.

Do what do you, just make sure to be consistent.

You might also want to check:

- https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/containers/About/About.js
- https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/login/LoginScreen.js
- https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/common/ViewPager.js
- http://reactkungfu.com/2015/09/common-react-dot-js-mistakes-unneeded-state/

Comment: Thanks for your point of view. I am intuitively following your pattern as well but it feels a bit overwhelming sometimes for the tiny menus, the tiny animations.
I guess I could do some destructuring into smaller components to feel less filled with that many variables...

Comment: @Florent you're right, see f8app I linked above, that's a professional app. They rarely use more than two states per component. For long forms, see redux-form